# Ionic CSS gradient colors off

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

I'm using the code below to make an `ion-button` have a gradient.

```
--background: linear-gradient(to right, #E49273, #DB6E44);
```

I'm trying to replicate a mockup I made in Affinity Photo, but the colors are completely different despite using the same hex.

CSS on the left, Mockup on the right

[image: Diff in colors]

When I use the photo editor and get the hexes from the CSS render compare to the mockup, they are completely different. (`#C1734D` vs `#FE6835` and
`#CE9578` vs `#FE8E6E`).

Why is this so off and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<ion-button expand="block" shape="round" class="customButton">
   Click me
</ion-button>
```

scss

```
.customButton {
    // background: #db6e44; /* fallback for old browsers */
    // background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #e49273, #db6e44); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    // background: linear-gradient(
    //     to right,
    //     #e49273,
    //     #db6e44
    // ); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    --background: #db6e44; /* fallback for old browsers */
    --background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #e49273, #db6e44); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    --background: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        #e49273,
        #db6e44
    ); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}
```